# Why in this theorem the field of characteristic equal to $2$ excluded?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, multilinear-algebra

> Theorem:
>
> Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ (where it is *not of
>   characteristic two*). Then, there is a one-to-one correspondence
>   between symmetric bilinear forms and quadratic forms.

I already proved that. Why here do we exclude the field of characteristic equal to two? What happens in that case? 
Thanks.

Comment: The main formula you use to prove that theorem contains a fraction $\frac12$.

Comment: @Amin $2 = 0$ in characteristic $2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard proof is this: if $B$ is a symmetric bilinear form and you define $q(v)=B(v,v)$, then you get a quadratic form. And how can you get $B$ from $q$ (in order to prove that this correspondence is one-to-one)? It turns out that$$B(v,w)=\frac12\bigl(B(v+w,v+w)-B(v,v)-B(w,w)\bigr).$$Problem: you can't divide by $2$ in a field whose characteristic is $2$, because in such a field $2=1+1=0$.